# Is it possible to add functionality to Vista/7 taskmgr.exe?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, taskmanager

I was wondering if anyone knew whether taskmgr.exe in Windows Vista/7 was extend-able via a plugin system.

I found [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/Task_Manager_Extension.aspx), but this is limited to XP,2k3 and he specifically states he didn't know about vista's and seven's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is not possible to extend `Task Manager` with some kind of plugin. App from the link is just a new app that mimics a regular `Task Manager` and add some functionality.

It is however possible to bind a new app to be executed instead of a normal `Task Manager`.

Comment: One excellent example of this is http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx Process Explorer, which can optionally register itself to launch instead of Task Manager.